# Need to arrange the point features in a row or inverted triangle

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, offset

Need to arrange the overlapping point features in a row or inverted triangle which are [image]in same layer with 0.1 offset.

enter image description here

[image]ps://i.stack.imgur.com/B8idh.png

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Qgis 3.4 version